# userfunc condition for detecting mobile device

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.x

Since TYPO3 7 the condition 'device' and 'useragent' are deprecated. No I'm looking for a userFunc to use as a condition for detecting mobile devices. My aim is to hide or to show some special pages on mobile devices. 
I used the extension 'contexts_wurfl' for a while but I guess that there should be 'smaller solutions'.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this with TypoScript using the PAGE Object.

The code below shows you how to execute your own code before executing something else (like the template engine/content rendering etcetera).

```
page.01 = USER_INT
page.01 {
    userFunc = TYPO3\MyExt\Utility\MobileDeviceUtility->detectMobileDevice
}
```

And in code:

```
<?php
namespace TYPO3\MyExt\Utility;

class MobileDeviceUtility {

    /**
     * Is Mobile Device
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    static public function isMobileDevice() {

        // calculates if the user agent is on a mobile device

        return TRUE;
    }

    /**
     * Detect Mobile Device
     *
     * @param string $content
     * @param array $conf
     * @return void
     */ 
    static public function detectMobileDevice($content, array $conf = NULL) {

        global $TSFE;

        if (self::isMobileDevice()
              && (boolean) $TSFE->page['mycustom_device_checkbox']
        ) {
            // do something 
        }

    }

}
```

OR otherwise you should create your own condition `[YourVendor\YourPackage\YourCondition = var1 = value1, var2 != value2, ...]`.

Comment: I have no experience with php so I don't understand exactly what I have to add by myself in the file. I was hoping for something like "[userFunc = detectMobileDevice] # do something [end]" to use in a template. Then I can hide or show pages with TS.

Comment: Then still you have to use a php script to calculate the result of your custom condition (eg. [YourVendor\YourPackage\YourCondition = var1 = value1, var2 != value2, ...])

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to avoid writing a custom user function the `globalString` function of Typo3 can still be used in the later versions of Typo3 to access the useragent and other information like this:

```
[globalString = IENV:HTTP_USER_AGENT = *<User-Agent>*]
  # Statements here will only affect browsers with the useragent matching <User-Agent>
[else]
  # Statements here will only affect browsers with the useragent not matching <User-Agent>
[end]
```

Detailed documentation for conditions using `globalString`can be found [here](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/8.7/Conditions/Reference/Index.html#globalstring).

A Full list of variables that can be used with the `globalString` function can be found [here](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/DataTypes/Index.html#getindpenv).

To execute different typoscript for mobile and stationary devices I found the following snippet to be working for Typo3 8.7 LTS and 9.5 LTS:

```
[globalString = IENV:HTTP_USER_AGENT = *Android*]||[globalString = IENV:HTTP_USER_AGENT = *iPhone*]||[globalString = IENV:HTTP_USER_AGENT = *Mobile*]||[globalString = IENV:HTTP_USER_AGENT = *Windows Phone*]
  # Statements for mobile devices only
[else]
  # Statements for stationary devices only
[end]
```